# ObservableList<String> and addListener

Tags: java, javafx

I am a beginner in java. My problem is quite simple but i have grinded hours with trying to search and solve my problem with no succeed.

The problem is: 
I made an ObservableList list named items and put it on the BorderPane called piir. In my program(showed below) i added Listener to it. When i click on a one element in items my textfield prints "pohka". My expectation is when i click on a specific element i get a specific change.

For example:
When i click on "Toora" i want to get a String "õige" in my textfield.
When i click on "Piibel" i want to get a String "vale" in my textfield.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    BorderPane piir = new BorderPane();

    TextField tekst = new TextField();
    tekst.setText("Millised järgnevatest on judaistlikud tekstid?");
    piir.setTop(tekst);


    ListView<String> list = new ListView<String>();
      ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Koraan", "Toora", "Piibel", "Talmud", "Veedad");
      list.setItems(items);
      piir.setCenter(list);

      //Reaction is same with each clicked element
      //But i want specific reaction on each clicked element
      list.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            tekst.setText("Pohka");
          }
      });

    Scene stseen1 = new Scene(piir, 500, 150, Color.SNOW);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Esimene küsimus");
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setScene(stseen1);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Im sorry if this is asked before, I did not find the answer.
Thanks in return.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want it to do. Are you just looking for `tekst.setText(newValue);`?

Comment: You're working with JavaFX before knowing trivial Java branching? Have you ever heard of an if statement?

Comment: Im trying to get different tekst.setText(newValue) for each clicked element in that list. If i click on "Koraan" then tekst.setText("False") and on "Toora" then Tekst.setText("True").
I am familiar with if statement, but how can i get specific element from that list when clicked?

Comment: `newValue` holds the selected item.

Comment: Oh yes, i got my solution. Thank you very much MouseEvent!
Also can i use newValue outside of changed() method?

Comment: No but you can always query the current selected item with `list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()`